# uses-permission-sdk-23 is not applied on some devices (SONY, LGE, HTC)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

We utilize `uses-permission-sdk-23` to requests the `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission on devices that are running sdk 23 or higher:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
    android:required="false"/>
```

The target sdk version of the app is 22 and the code that requires the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission is guarded with:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    return;
}
```

Till now this was working as expected. But currently we observe an increasing number of Security Exceptions:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user xxxxx nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
```

The crash affects only ~0.5% of our users on 6.0 and is mostly limited to the following manufacturer/devices combinations:

- SONY - Xperia Z5 (Normal/Compact/Premium)
- LGE - G3/G4
- HTC - One
  M8/M9/Desire 816

Is there some general flaw in the described strategy or is this just another case of manufacturer screwed it up and we need another `try -> catch -> blame them block?`

Comment: Note that there is no `android:required` attribute for either `<uses-permission>` or `<uses-permission-sdk23>`. What specific API(s) are you calling that is generating the crash? Are you sure that you have the runtime permission when you are making those calls?

Comment: The crash happens while calling `WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()`. As mentioned, the code is running without crashing for >99% of our users on 6.0. Till now we didn't explicitly check that we have the permission because there is now way for the user to revoke this permission (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: Oh, wait, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` isn't `dangerous`. I thought that it was, given that you are using `<uses-permission-sdk23>`. Only `dangerous` permissions need to be requested at runtime.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you still need to request permissions in the Manifest that aren't dangerous? At least if I remove the `<uses-permission-sdk23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">` part the app crashes with the `SecurityException`

Comment: "Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you still need to request permissions in the Manifest that aren't dangerous?" -- correct. However, `<uses-permission-sdk23>` was added with an eye towards runtime permissions. Personally, I would use `<uses-permission>` for `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`.

Comment: This permission is not required to experience the core features of the app. So we decided to only utilize/provide it on devices that automatically provide this without annoying all users on lower versions with the permission screen during the app update. So this seems to be just some case that these manufacturers didn't test?

Comment: Using `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` is the only thing that I see that is somewhat odd about your scenario. If requesting `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` were broken in general, I would expect more screaming. I don't have one of your listed devices. My closest is an HTC A9, and that handles `<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />` without issue.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. It seems that this crash also doesn't occur on all devices of a affected model. However if a user had the crash once he will have it permanently.